# If b6 equals A, subtract randbetween(1,10) from H3, otherwise return "oof". Gives parse error

Tags: google-sheets

For some reason, it won't work.

```
=IF(EQ(B6, a), =MINUS(H3, =RANDBETWEEN(1, 10)), "oof")
```

H3 is `=N(100)`.
Trying to make a simple HP system.

Comment: shouldn't it be "a" ?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

`=IF(EQ(B6, "a"), MINUS(H3, RANDBETWEEN(1, 10)), "oof")`